# What is best practice for commiting a git repository?

Tags: git

When updating my git repository after changes, I normally issue the following commands:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'changes'
```

If I delete files during the session and run `git add .`, will this add these files to the repository again?

What's the best approach for covering everything during a commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practice would probably be:

- use a [.gitignore file](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.gitignore)
- use the staging area
- review your changes as you commit

If you are only editing files for example:

```
git commit -va
```

That will add all changed files and open your configured editor so you can write the commit message. Under the commit message are the changes you are going to commit in diff format.

If you have more changes in your working copy, and only want to commit some of them **use the staging area**:

```
git add this
git rm that

git status
# On branch foo
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
# deleted:  that
# modified: this
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
# ....

git commit -v
```

Again, using a verbose commit (show diff) and no message (so the editor opens) allows you easy control without missing anything.

If you close the editor without typing a commit message, the commit will be aborted. Quite often just skimming the diff - or even just the list of files to be commited - you'll notice something missing or wrong and want to correct that.

using `git add .` will add all files that you aren't explicitly ignoring with your `.gitignore` files. That's probably not the best way to commit by default, no doubt you've already committed files you didn't really want in your repository that way.

If you `git rm` a file, recreate the file, are not `.gitignore`ing the file and then run `git add .` - you will just add the file back to the staged changes to be made in your next commit (which will then either be an edit to the file you originally deleted, or no action because the contents haven't changed).

Answer (score 2):

`git add -A .`

Will add all files added, modified or deleted (`-A`) in the subfolders starting from the folder you're currently in (`.`).

Best practice is to always check after doing a git add with:

`git status`

Another nice thing to do is to add an alias, so you don't always have to type in everything.
Add the following to your .gitconfig file:

```
[alias]
aa = add -A
c = commit -m
pp = !git pull && git push
```

After adding this, you can just use the following:

```
git aa                    -- add all
git c "some commit"       -- commit
git pp                    -- pull first, push after pull
```

Answer (score -1):

use

```
git status
```

you will get a suggestion

Comment: this answer is not useful @Anonymoose - how does it answer the question?